# How to tell my LinuxMint system to update DNS server when using Python's protonvpn-cli?

Tags: linux, dns, resolv.conf

When I run by example:

```
protonvpn-cli connect --fastest --protocol udp
```

the DNS domain names are not resolved. I need to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` to put (bogon IP):

```
nameserver 10.2.0.1
```

How can I tell the system to do this as regular user automatically? polkit rule ? Anything simpler ?

I use latest LinuxMint Victoria:

- NetworkManager 1.36.6
- protonvpn-cli 3.13.0
- protonvpn-nm-lib 3.16.0

I prefer not to use `sudo` in a regular user script.